# WPF: Refine the look of a grouped ComboBox vs. a grouped DataGrid -sample attached -

Tags: wpf, combobox, grouping

just watch this screenshot I made so you see the difference:

I have these requirments to be changed in the ComboBox`s PopUp so it looks like the grouped WPF DataGrid, its only about the Popup-area, do not judge the editable area of the ComboBox or that there is no Header... Important are these things, because I could not change them:

ComboBox:

1. (Green Line) The alternating
   Background of the Item must start at
   the beginning
2. (Red Line) The TextBlocks within the
   Border must be aligned Center OR
   Right1.
3. (Blue) The weakly visible horizontal
   Border must always stretch to the
   right side or take all space2.

   to 1.) I have no idea why there is a margin
   to 2.) HorizontalAlignment of the TextBlock does not work
   to 3.) I can make the  stackpanel in the ItemTemplate of the Combobox a read background then you can see very well the red color has a margin somehow on the right and left side. Have no idea how to remove that.

Anyone can help, please?

If you want to see the textbox live just download it here:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/6lmbrh

Its a 30 kb VS2010 .NET 4.0 project.

[image]

Here is the XAML for the ComboBox:

```
<Window  x:Class="TestComboGrouped.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ComboBox.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ComboBox.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" StartPoint="0.5,0.0" EndPoint="0.5,1.0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFF" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE4F0FC" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCEDFF6" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 0 0 1" />           
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"/>
        </Style>

        <!-- Grouped CollectionView -->
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding WeeklyDateList,IsAsync=False}" x:Key="WeeklyView">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MonthName"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=WeeklyView}}"      
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
            AlternationCount="2" 
            MaxDropDownHeight="300" 
            Width="Auto" 
            x:Name="comboBox"
            >
            <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock 
                               Padding="5,0,0,0"
                                Background="White" 
                                Foreground="DarkBlue" 
                                FontSize="14" 
                                FontWeight="DemiBold" 
                                Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxBorderStyle}">
                            <TextBlock Width="100" Foreground="Purple"  Text="{Binding WeeklyLessonDate, StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxBorderStyle}">
                            <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0"  Width="40"   Text="{Binding WeekNumber}"/>
                        </Border>                    
                    </StackPanel>                   
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>   
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>1.2.
```

**UPDATE**:

@Meleak thats the updated image it looks very nice thanks to you:
[image]

I was just about to put my old  2-"ColumnHeader" in that ComboBox`s Popup top area but I could not find anymore my sample... seems due to changing/trying a lot I have overritten that code :/ I know I did it in the controltemplate above the scrollviewer with a stackpanel or a grid with 2 rowdefinitions. But your code looks now totally different to my default combobox controltemplate I have no idea how to merge both code snippets.

I think that was the code where I put the 2 "column headers", just search for inside the POPUP

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                                <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
```

// **Here should be the column headers, but how merge your code with the ItemsPresenter?**

```
                                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                                </Canvas>
                                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                                </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                            </Popup>
                            <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Did you try my answer? I think it looks pretty close to your left picture.

Comment: ah yes of course you actually already have the solution. It looks very nice. Should I make a new thread for the column headers Meleak?

Comment: Can you upload a new sample project so I can look at it?

Comment: Maybe best to create a new question for this, this one is becoming pretty big :)

Comment: ok marked your answer as solution! Doing now a new question on the column header but really Meleak, my sample project is the one you alreay have... What I did before was copy the default combobox controltemplate from msdn and changed it by putting a stackpanel around the scrollviewer and a grid inside at the top with 2 textblocks. More I can`t give because I have not more, but I will search again for my old code maybe its somewhere out commented and I overlooked it...

Comment: its there => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117342/put-a-column-header-over-the-scrollviewer-of-a-wpf-combobox-controltemplate

Comment: @Meleak I have also found my old Code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it looks pretty close. You can download my modified version from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?a7s7rj5vblf5aox)

[image]

Added a template for ComboBoxItem

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Margin="-5,0,0,0"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Name="border1"
                            BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
                            BorderBrush="#FFCEDFF6"
                            Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Purple"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                   Margin="0,0,2,0"
                                   Text="{Binding WeeklyLessonDate, StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Name="border2"
                            BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
                            BorderBrush="#FFCEDFF6"
                            Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Text="{Binding WeekNumber}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="border1" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="border2" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ComboBox.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ComboBox.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" StartPoint="0.5,0.0" EndPoint="0.5,1.0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFF" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE4F0FC" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: ok Meleak this time it seems I have to prefer your solution before Vlad`s ;-) Please see my updated question above.